# To transform the XML file while exporting from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a requirement to transform the XML format of the SSRS report while exporting. I tried with some XSLT to implement this, but not getting desried output.

Default XML format of my report is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Report xsi:schemaLocation="Test http://reportserver?    %2FTest&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="Test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Test">
  <Tablix1>
  <Details_Collection>
  <Details Country="India" Sales="1000.0000" />
  </Details_Collection>
  </Tablix1>
</Report>
```

Output Needed (Report Tag is removed and the look and feel should be changed as below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Tablix1>
<Details_Collection>
<Details>
    < Country>"India"</COuntry>
     <Sales>1000.0000</Sales>
</Details>

</Details_Collection>
</Tablix1>
```

Br,

Shamsuddeen

Comment: Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found second part of transformation:

```
<Details Country="India" Sales="1000.0000" /> 

->
 < Country>"India"</Country>
 <Sales>1000.0000</Sales>
```

For this purpose you should use TexBox Properties.

1. Press on your Data Filed in Designer mode
2. Find DataElementOutput - Set Output
3. Find DataElementStyle -Set Element

After that - you'll receive that you wanted.
But first part of transformation I could'n do.
I mean - remove `<Report xsi:schemaLocation="Test http://reportserver?......>`
If you already have a solution - advice.
BR,
Timur